# Al hacer una conversión con parseInt() se detiene la aplicación, error: NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Tags: java, android

```
    EditText numero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView muestra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button calculo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    final int entero = Integer.parseInt(numero.getText().toString());

    calculo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
                acu = acu*i;
            }
            muestra.setText(acu+"");

        }
    });
```

ya detecté que la aplicación se detiene en:

```
final int entero = Integer.parseInt(numero.getText().toString());
```

le quité final y lo hice público, privado, etc pero aún así no corre

Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.misd_nancy.factorial, PID:
>   5899 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.misd_nancy.factorial/com.example.misd_nancy.factorial.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74410/discussion-on-question-by-nancy-al-hacer-una-conversion-con-parseint-se-detiene).

Answer (score 1):

El error es provocado porque tu `EditText` puede contener valores que no son numéricos, y al tratar de convertirlos obtendrás un error, en este caso puedes ver que tratas de convertir un String vació en un entero lo cual no es posible.

> .NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Te sugiero validar utilizando este método:

```
public static int isNumeric(String number){
    int result = 0; //Valor default si no es numerico.
    try{
        if(number != null){
            result = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        Log.w(TAG, "NFException value: " + number);
    }
    return result;
}
```

y usarlo de esta forma (Es recomendable usar el método `trim()` para eliminar los espacios vacios en los extremos):

```
 final int entero = isNumeric(numero.getText().trim().toString());
```

Comment: admiro tu voluntad de apoyo a los demás y sobre todo el dominio de conocimiento hacia lo que te gusta, Dios te bendiga siempre, gracias y saludos!!

Comment: puedes marcar la pregunta como correcta, ayudarias a jorge a seguir respondiendo y a ayudar a la comunidad ;) @Nancy