# Introducción de datos y suma automática sin necesidad de botón "Calcular"

Tags: java, android, studio

Tengo un layout con 1 spinner, dos EditText y un TextView en donde el usuario introduce valores.

Quiero conseguir que en el momento en que el usuario elija una opción del spinner el programa me calcule el resultado de la elección del spinner más la suma de los dos EditText, tanto si se han introducido datos en los EditText como si continuan vacios, es decir, sin tener la necesidad de pulsar un botón para que se ejecute el cálculo, y que a su vez me muestre el resultado en el TextView.

Me he quedado atascado y no sé como continuar, os dejo lo que tengo hecho a ver si alguien me indica como conseguirlo.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner cantidades;
Integer[] cantidades1 = {1,2,3,4 };
int cantidad1 = 0;int cantidad2 = 0;int cantidad3 = 0;int Resultado = 0;

private EditText et_Cantidad2, et_Cantidad3;
private TextView tv_Resultado;
public static int isNumeric(String number){

    int result = 0; //Valor default si no es numerico.
    try{
        if(number != null){
            result = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        //Log.w(TAG, "NFException value: " + number);
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );

    cantidades = (Spinner) findViewById ( R.id.spinner );
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> AdaptadorCantidad1 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer> ( this, androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cantidades1  );
    cantidades.setAdapter ( AdaptadorCantidad1 );

    et_Cantidad2 = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.editTextNumber1 );
    et_Cantidad3 = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.editTextNumber2 );
    tv_Resultado = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.textView );
    //String number;




    cantidades.setOnItemSelectedListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    cantidad1 = 8;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cantidad1 = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cantidad1 = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cantidad1 = 3;
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    } );

    //Obtiene valores de EditText.
    int cantidad2 = isNumeric(et_Cantidad2.getText().toString());
    int cantidad3 = isNumeric(et_Cantidad3.getText().toString());
    int resultado = cantidad1 + cantidad2 + cantidad3;

    //Muestra resultado.
    tv_Resultado.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
}
```

}
Layout
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="411dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumber1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Cantidad 1"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumber2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Cantidad 2"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumber1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="156dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Resultado"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumber2" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Viendo la primera parte del código, creo que te falta entender y practicar las bases de programación con android ya que te falta el concepto de eventos lo cual es necesario que aprendas para resolver el ejercicio que estás planteando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro del mismo método `onItemSelected()` puedes realizar la operación, simplemente, obtén el valor entero que contienen los `EditText` y posteriormente realiza la operación que deseas.

Primero agrega el siguiente método para obtener el valor de los EditText, en caso de que estos no contengan un valor numerico, su valor predeterminado será 0, revisa [respuesta1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/145642/95)  [respuesta2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26698/95).

```
public static int isNumeric(String number){
    int result = 0; //Valor default si no es numerico.
    try{
        if(number != null){
            result = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        //Log.w(TAG, "NFException value: " + number);
    }
    return result;
}
```

ahora usa el método anterior de esta forma:

```
Cantidades.setOnItemSelectedListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Cantidad1 = 0;           
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Cantidad1 = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Cantidad1 = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Cantidad1 = 3;
                    break;
            }

           //Obtiene valores de EditText.
           int cantidad2 = isNumeric(et_Cantidad2.getText().toString());
           int cantidad3 = isNumeric(et_Cantidad3.getText().toString());
           int resultado = Cantidad1 + Cantidad2 + Cantidad3;

           //Muestra resultado.
           tv_Resultado.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));

        }
```

Comment: Antes de nada quiero agradecer la ayuda, cuando intento implementar el método isNumeric me muestra varios errores, me pregunto si se debe importar alguna libreria.?

Comment: Solo las estandar, pero cual es el error que te muestra?

Comment: Solucionado el error que me mostraba al implementar el método, era un descuido mio.
Jorgesys, con el método que me has indicado la comprobación se hace perfectamente, el problema que tengo ahora es que no me muestra el resultado de la introducción de los datos del spinner ni de los EditText, no pensaba que fuera tan complicado que te muestre el resultado sin la creación del típico botón "Calcular". He editado el código a como lo tengo ahora.

Comment: Te sugiero que no edites el código original, ya que pierde sentido la respuesta, puedes editar y agregar el código que quedo o mucho mejor hacer otra pregunta para que tenga mejor apoyo de varios otros desarrolladores.

Comment: Lo siento, pensaba que era mejor editar que poner otra pregunta, lo tendré en cuenta en el futuro.

Comment: No te muestra el resultado con llamar :  tv_Resultado.setText(String.valueOf(resultado)); ?

Comment: Correcto, solamente me muestra el resultado del valor que recoge del spinner, el valor de los EditText no.